# $\lim_{k \to \infty} {\chi}_{B(x_k , r_k)} = {\chi}_{B(x_0 , r_0)}$ if $(x_k , r_k)\to(x_0 , r_0)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{(x_k , r_k)\}$ a sequence in ${\mathbb{R}}^n \times (0 , \infty)$ and let $(x_0 , r_0)$ be a point in ${\mathbb{R}}^n \times (0 , \infty)$ such that $(x_k , r_k) \to (x_0 , r_0)$. Then I have to show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} {\chi}_{B(x_k , r_k)}(y) = {\chi}_{B(x_0 , r_0)}(y)$ for almost any point $y \in {\mathbb{R}}^n$ ($\chi_A(y)$ is the characteristic function of a set $A \subset {\mathbb{R}}^n$, given by $1$ if $y \in A$ and $0$ otherwise).

To show that, the way is to see it for ALL $y \in B(x_0 , r_0)$ and for ALL $y \in Ext(B(x_0 , r_0)) = {\mathbb{R}}^n \setminus \overline{B(x_0 , r_0)}$, so the points $y \in {\mathbb{R}}^n$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} {\chi}_{B(x_k , r_k)}(y) \neq {\chi}_{B(x_0 , r_0)}(y)$ should belong to $\partial B(x_0 , r_0) = \{x \in {\mathbb{R}}^n : \|x - x_0\| = r\}$, but the statement is true, as this set has null (Lebesgue) measure.

It is clear what we need to prove. For example, let $y \in B(x_0 , r_0)$. How can we show that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} {\chi}_{B(x_k , r_k)}(y) = {\chi}_{B(x_0 , r_0)}(y) = 1?
$$
Should we consider the operator $G : (x , r) \mapsto {\chi}_{B(x , r)}$ and see some property

Comment: If $r_k \downarrow r_0,$ then the sequence converges to the closed ball and if $r_k \uparrow r_0,$ then the sequence converges to the open ball. The frontier has measure zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y\in B(x_0,r_0)$, $|y-x_0| = r_0-\eta$ for some fixed $\eta>0$. Recall that $x_k\to x_0$. So, for $k$ large enough, $|x_k-x_0|< \epsilon$. Then

$$|y-x_k| = |y-x_0+x_0-x_k| \leq |y-x_0| + |x_k-x_0| < r_0 - \eta + \epsilon.$$

Similarly, since $r_k\to r_0$, for $k$ large enough, $r_0 < r_k + \delta$. Thus

$$|y-x_k|< r_0 - \eta + \epsilon < r_k + \delta -\eta + \epsilon.$$

Now choose $\epsilon + \delta < \eta$ and we are done.

Comment: why is $r_0 < r_k + \delta$? what if $r_k \leq r_0$?

Comment: Because $r_k\to r_0$. It means that, for some $N$ large enough, for all $k>N$, $|r_0-r_k|<\delta$. Expand the absolute value: $-\delta < r_0-r_k<\delta\implies r_k-\delta < r_0 < r_k + \delta$. It does not matter if $r_k\leq r_0$, we are free to pick $\delta$ as small as we want.

Comment: I see thank you!